# C# formatting a number with thousand separators but keeping the decimal places count as is

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I want to add a thousands separator to a `double` number but want to keep the decimal places as is i.e. dont want any rounding.

`#,#` is solving my problem of adding the thousand separator but how do I preserve the decimal places ? `#,#` strips off the part after `.`.

I cannot use any culture or something like that & the developer whose function I am calling has only given me a way of changing the format by passing as parameter `strFormat`.

I did check other posts & even the docs but somehow not able to figure this out.

```
string strFormat = "#,#";
string str = double.parse("912123456.1123465789").ToString(strFormat);
 //Expected here 912,123,456.1123465789 
//Actual Output 912,123,456

//912123456.123 should give 912,123,456.123
//912123456.1 should give 912,123,456.1
//912123456.1123465789 should give 912,123,456.1123465789
//912123456 should give 912,123,456
```

Comment: It would be easy for everyone to suggest something, if you post what is "actually" assigned. Did you see any rounding issues?

Comment: @Thangadurai updated the question with actual output.

Comment: How about `"#,##0.#"`? http://www.tutorialspanel.com/string-format-in-csharp-for-decimal/index.htm

Comment: Also, are there negative numbers?

Comment: @Paul there could be negative numbers

Comment: @Paul #,##0.# is also stripping the parts after the dot.

Comment: Have you tried `#,##0.##########`?  Seems a dirty option, but if it works in the meantime...

Comment: @Paul I do not know how many decimal places it would go. but yes it is dirty solution

Answer (score 1):

If you know the max number of decimal places, e.g. 10, then use:

```
string strFormat = "#,#0.##########";
```

**Update:**

This max number is known.
According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-5.0) a Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision (including both before and after the decimal point). More than 15 digits will be rounded.

So if you must invoke that method of 'double.parse' and can only send the format, this is the best you can do:

```
string strFormat = "#,#0.###############";
```

Comment: You're missing one `#` between the comma and the `0`.

Comment: @Paul It seems to work fine as is. What is the second `#` needed for?

Comment: You're wanting to represent the thousand delimiter (9,999,999.999999999).  I suspect, that if you test your code, you may find that you get 9,99,99,99.999999999...

Answer (score 1):

Well, after looking at the documentation [on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), it would appear that there is no particular way to allow a floating point position in a number - all characters in a format string are character placeholders.

I would recommend that you either use a very nasty predetermined number of `#`s to set the width of the decimal position, or the slightly less (or possibly more, depending on your outlook) nasty option of reading all numbers into an array, determining the longest decimal position, then building a format of `#`s using the result.

At the end of the day, this is a single format string that you can put into place, test and ensure it works, then come back later and fix if you find a better alternative.

Also, this is one of those things where you could put the string into a configuration setting and change as and when you need to - far more flexible.

To be honest, this is a very slight thing to be worried about in the grand scheme of performance and writing a program.

Technically, Udi Y gets my vote!

Comment: Its not about performance, it is about user satisfaction & making things work in a defined box which is very stringent.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed - Yeah - unfortunately, I don't think C# will get it perfect on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the formatting dynamically for each number:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var number = 1234.12312323123;

    var format = GetNumberFormat(number);
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToString(format));
}

public static string GetNumberFormat(double number)
{
    var numberAsString = number.ToString();

    var decimalPartSize = numberAsString.Substring(numberAsString.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).Length;

    return $"N{decimalPartSize}";
}
```

So

```
number = 1234.12312323123
```

will give you `1,234.12312323123`. Works for negative numbers as well. Also, as we work with strings, there won't be any rounding errors or precision artifacts.

Comment: Just curious, why is the only working solution here voted down?

Comment: I dont have the liberty of doing this as i can only pass the format from outside. (Have mentioned that in the question)

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed You can only set the format once or for each separate call? The example that you have given uses exactly ToString() with a formating. Either provide actual code invocation or state exactly what your environment is as currently there is a mismatch. There are different solutions for different problems.

Comment: I can only pass the parameter once. I think i have mentioned that in question.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed "I cannot use any culture or something like that & the developer whose function I am calling has only given me a way of changing the format by passing as parameter strFormat." - No, you haven't mentioned you only call the function once. That's the whole point of you providing code in order for the people to be able to help you.